# Does a (half) beheaded Ettin take bleeding damage of some sort?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, injury

Let's say a character cuts off one of an Ettin's heads, but the other head is still intact, and it's as such still alive. Obviously, there's a lot of blood. Does the Ettin take continuous damage from naturally bleeding out? Or does it not work that way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### The DM decides the effect

Although things like limb loss and hit locations aren't generally used in D&D, the [Sword of Sharpness](https://roll20.net/compendium/dnd5e/Sword%20of%20Sharpness) description provides a good *edge* case example: "*you lop off one of the target’s limbs, with the effect of such loss determined by the GM*".

For my own games: whenever a player reduces an opponent to 0 hp with a melee attack, I'm ok with describing the defeat however we want: dead, unconscious, disarmed, lost limb, etc.

Answer (score 2):

## No, it does not

For several reasons:

1. There are no called shots in 5e. Unless there is a mechanic for removing a head (e.g. the Hydra in the Monster Manual p. 190 or the Vorpal Sword from the DMG p. 209), there is no way to remove a head without houserules. Should a head be removed, there are mechanics in the stat block for that; remove a head and remove those mechanics.

   > **Two Heads**
   >
   > The ettin has advantage on Wisdom (Perception)
   >   checks and on saving throws against being blinded, charmed,
   >   deafened, frightened, stunned, and knocked unconscious
   >
   > **Wakeful**
   >
   > When one of the ettin's heads is asleep, its other head is awake

   (MM, 132)
2. The stat block of the Ettin provides no damage for loss of a head. Just loss of some mechanical advantages (see above.)
3. Unless you have a weapon or effect that specifically causes bleeding (e.g. Sword of Wounding from DMG p. 207), there are no ongoing bleeding effects from damage.

Comment: I think #1 could use more qualifiers, since between vorpal swords, and DMs ruling on results of PC actions that the rules don't systematise (e.g., PC: "okay, now that we have the chained ettin in the guillotine, I pull the lever…"), such a situation could easily arise without house rules.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie the Vorpal Sword is a good point, but it's impossible to come up with an edge-case resolution for something that doesn't have mechanical rules in the system. I'm actually going to do a follow-up question on the Vorpal sword.

Comment: Vorpal answered here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110606