# When partially beheaded, does an Ettin retain full control of its body?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters

There are more then a few sources which depict two-headed humanoids (such as ettins) having more control over some limbs than others - the left head uses the left arm to punch the right head, and such. If an Ettin was to lose one head, would it lose control of the arms that were primarily controlled by that head?

To put it another way: Let's say the ettin's left head controls the left leg and arm, and the right head controls the right leg and arm. The two normally work in tandem to function. However, let's now say the left head is decapitated. Would the right head lose control of the left arm and leg? Or would it "inherit" control of those limbs from the left head, resulting in the Ettin still be able to function fully? I mean, I'd assume both heads share the same nervous system to some extent, but would the left head's nervous system extend to use both arms when one head dies?

Comment: I'm not sure why this was marked as a duplicate of [Does a (half) beheaded Ettin take bleeding damage of some sort?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110780/does-a-half-beheaded-ettin-take-bleeding-damage-of-some-sort), since they appear to be distinctly different questions. I've reopened this, but I'm open to being convinced otherwise if there's some circumstance I've missed.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I marked it as a duplicate because it is essentially the same question ( what are the effects on an ettin when it loses a head) with the same answer. Otherwise I could submit additional variables that are all asking the same thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Yes

A single Ettin head retains control of the body.

> **Wakeful**
>
> When one of the ettin's heads is asleep, its other head is awake

(MM, 132)

This shows that each head maintains total control. I imagine they both share control so the self-fighting is a literal depiction of a fight for control of the body.

Comment: You should extend your answer to include a clear statement answering the question posed as you are dead on! I'd write an answer but I would feel bad about stealing your thunder!

Comment: @Protonflux I have made an update, if you still think if could be clearer go ahead and steal my thunder :)